# Reload DataGridview when ComboBox Item selection Changed

Tags: c#, combobox, datagrid

I created a form which have a DataGrid and it's load from an excel file. I want to show excel file sheet name  in a combo box. I found my solution to show excel sheet name to my combo box. But i want when i changed my combobox item the datagridview populate depend on excel sheet which i change my combo box.
[IMG]http://i67.tinypic.com/153l82v.jpg[/IMG]
How can i do that?
 My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
namespace excel2access
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        string FilePath;
        string CB;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog OpenFD = new OpenFileDialog();
            OpenFD.FileName = "";
            OpenFD.Title = "Choose Excel file to Upload Data ";
            OpenFD.DefaultExt = "xls";
            OpenFD.Filter = "Ms-Excel Files (*.xls)|*.xls|All Files|*.*";

            if (OpenFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FilePath = OpenFD.InitialDirectory + OpenFD.FileName;//Code to get FullPath, Filename and extension
                textBox1.Text = FilePath;
                string excelConnStr = string.Empty;
                OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand();
                if (FilePath.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    //2007 Format
                    excelConnStr =string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'", FilePath);
                }
                else
                {
                    //2003 Format
                   excelConnStr= string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'", FilePath);
                }
                //Get the Sheets in Excel Workbook                
                OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnStr);
                OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
                OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                cmdExcel.Connection = excelConn;
                excelConn.Open();
                comboBox1.DataSource = excelConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";
                CB = comboBox1.DisplayMember;
                DataTable dtsheet = new DataTable();
                dtsheet = excelConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);                
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + comboBox1.Text + "]", excelConnStr);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Fine, Is your current code is working? are you getting the grid populated? Have you defined the selection changed event for the combobox ?

Comment: my code is working and i get name of excel sheet name as 'Sheet1$'. i want when i select Sheet2 my datagrid data populate on sheet2. I could not solve that porblem.

Comment: Can you please have a look into my answer? Please let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: Its show an error. Additional information '$' is not valid name. Make sure that it dose not include invalid character or punctuation and that it is not too long. I think my sheet name is show as 'sheet1$' but its need to sheet1$ instate of 'sheet1$'. but how to get sheet name without single quote to my combobox1?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define SelectionChanged event for the comboBox1 and rebind the grid from that event. the code will be something like this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     string excelConnStr = string.Empty;
     OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand();
     if (FilePath.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
     {
         excelConnStr =string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'", FilePath);
     }
     else
     {
         excelConnStr= string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'", FilePath);
     }
     string selectedSheet= (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as string;
     OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnStr);
     OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
     OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
     cmdExcel.Connection = excelConn;
     excelConn.Open();
     DataTable dtsheet = new DataTable();
     dtsheet = excelConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);                
     OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + selectedSheet + "]", excelConnStr);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     da.Fill(dt);
     dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

In the above code `(sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as string;` will helps you to get the selected item from the combobox from selection changed event

Comment: Its show an error. Additional information '$' is not valid name. Make sure that it dose not include invalid character or punctuation and that it is not too long. I tried without $ sign. but not success. I think my sheet name is show as 'sheet1$' but its need to sheet1$ instate of 'sheet1$'. but how to get sheet name without single quote to my combobox1?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define SelectionIndexChanged event for the comboBox1 and rebind the grid from that event.

I have to suggest like when you load grid first time then multiple sheet data store in one data set with multiple table.

When user change drop down value then get data from that dataset so, you prevent multiple database hit.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
        }
```